# Laravel 4 - mirror database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

We have created mirror database which is replica of the main database of our application. The goal is to jump between two databases in case of unavailability.

I was wondering how can I implement such thing in Laravel 4 ? Lets say I have

```
 'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '172.22.22.22',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'db',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

and

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '172.22.22.23',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'db',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

basically different host but same credentials. How can I config switching between those databases in case one of them is unavailable? Any source or doc will be appreciated.

Comment: To me it seems like your best option would be having a load balancer do the dirty work of failover selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper function that sets the connection depending on connectivity or not. The way i would do it would be something like this:

Config file:

```
  # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Helper function file:

```
function db($modelName){
try {
//Get underlaying PDO connection.
DB::connection()->getPdo();
$m = new $modelName;
$m->setConnection('mysql');
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
 $m = new $modelName;
$m->setConnection('mysql2');
}
}
```

And then in every model file you would set this:

```
protected $connection = HelperClass::db('mymodelname');
```

I do presume some kind of approach like this would work.